# Sending email notifications depending on customer group - opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I have a question - Im using OC 2.2.0. I have two customer groups 1 and 4. I was wondering if it is possible to send new order notifications emails to different admin email addresses depending on customer group to which a buyer(customer) belongs? Meaning- if customer belongs to group 1, send to mail1@mail.com(which belongs to admin 1) and if the customer belongs to group 4, send notification mail to mail2@mail.com(which belongs to admin 2.

I tried adding to `model/checkout/order.php` the following:

```
if($customer_group_id != 1) {
                    $mail = new Mail();
                    $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
                    $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
                    $mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
                    $mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
                    $mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                    $mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
                    $mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

                    $mail->setTo(array(0 => 'somemail@gmail.com'));
                    $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
                    $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($order_info['store_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                    $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                    $mail->setHtml($this->load->view('mail/order', $data));
                    $mail->setText($text);
                    $mail->send();

                    // Send to additional alert emails
                    $emails = explode(',', $this->config->get('config_mail_alert'));

                    foreach ($emails as $email) {
                        if ($email && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                            $mail->setTo($email);
                            $mail->send();
                        }
                    }

                }

if($customer_group_id != 4) {
                    $mail = new Mail();
                    $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
                    $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
                    $mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
                    $mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
                    $mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                    $mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
                    $mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

                    $mail->setTo(array(0 => 'somemail@gmail.com'));
                    $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
                    $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($order_info['store_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                    $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                    $mail->setHtml($this->load->view('mail/order', $data));
                    $mail->setText($text);
                    $mail->send();

                    // Send to additional alert emails
                    $emails = explode(',', $this->config->get('config_mail_alert'));

                    foreach ($emails as $email) {
                        if ($email && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                            $mail->setTo($email);
                            $mail->send();
                        }
                    }

                }
```

but this always sends mail to both email addresses. I guess it doesn't recognise my customer groups. Where else should I define them? I didn't put real mail address in this example, obviously.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, I just needed to define customer groups in the same file `(model/checkout/order.php)` like this:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['customer_group_id']) && is_array($this->config->get('config_customer_group_display')) && in_array($this->request->get['customer_group_id'], $this->config->get('config_customer_group_display'))) {
            $customer_group_id = $this->request->get['customer_group_id'];
        } else {
            $customer_group_id = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
        }
```

I hope this helps someone. Cheers

Comment: Does that work on Opencart 3?

Comment: @Joe Haven't tried it myself on Opencart 3, sorry about that.